# Node.JS - SVG to Image Buffer for Sharp's overlayWith() Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, buffer, sharp

I'm using the [Sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) NPM library with Node.JS and I'm trying to add text to my canvas. I found out [here](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/477) that I need to use `.overlayWith()`, along with another library that can convert text to an SVG. [A comment there](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/477#issuecomment-243759784) suggested to use [text-to-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-to-svg) or [vectorize-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vectorize-text), but both of those, along with [text2svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text2svg), return an SVG. Sharp's `.overlayWith()` function requires an image Buffer. How can I convert the SVG that these libraries return, into an image Buffer for Sharp?

Comment: Please not if you're on Windows the libraries sharp uses aren't thread safe, so sometimes you get little squares instead of text. Still trying to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution: The NPM module [SVG2IMG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2img) takes an SVG string and converts it into an image Buffer.

Comment: Please provide sample code! I've spent two days on this and all I get it little squares right now :-(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a try to build your all svg context via [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/),

```
var draw = SVG(document.documentElement).size(width, height);
draw.text(text).font({
  family: 'tAsset.fontFamily',
  size: 'fontHeight',
  leading: '1.2em',
  anchor: "middle"
});
return draw.svg();
```

then use returned value in the sharp with creating new Buffer(svg).

```
sharp(buffer).overlayWith(new Buffer(svg), {
  top: model.top,
  left: model.left
}).toBuffer(function (error, data, info) {});
```